# Accordion not working after setinverval load

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

Code works fine but after setinverval ajax update, Accordion not working.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        function LoadXML() {
            $.ajax({
                crossOrigin: true,
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'Reuters.xml',
                dataType: 'xml',
                success: function (xml) {
                    var htmlstring = '';

                    $(xml).find('item').each(function () {
                        htmlstring += '<h3>' + $(this).find('title').text() + '</h3><div>' + $(this).find('description').text() + '</div>';
                    });

                    $('#accordianmenu').html(htmlstring).accordion();
                }
            });
        }

        LoadXML();

        setInterval(function () {
            LoadXML() // this will run after every 5 seconds
        }, 5000)
    });
```

Comment: Where is `accordianmenu`, and why do you need to re-accordion it with every call?

Comment: Using jquery-ui.js and jquery-ui.css for accordion property. I want to modify my heading and paragraph in a accordion menu

Comment: Per the [jQuery UI Documentation](https://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#method-refresh), you may be looking for `$(".selector").accordion("refresh");`: *"Process any headers and panels that were added or removed directly in the DOM and recompute the height of the accordion panels."*